# Getting proper OpenCL enqueue_kernel error codes

Tags: c++, opencl

I've got an OpenCL program that utilizes the enqueue_kernel function inside my parent kernel.

Currently, after enqueue_kernel is called, enqueue_kernel is returning "-11" as its error code.

The CLK_XXX error codes (enqueue_kernel's return values) listed in the spec are not enumerated anywhere in the docs or header files, so I don't know which code I'm getting. How can I get my kernel to return meaningful errors?

Also, the spec states that by enabling the "-g" flag during clBuildProgram, enqueue_kernel will return more verbose codes. However, when I add "-g" to my list of flags, I get a compilation error saying "-g" flag is not recognized. I have the latest NVidia drivers which officially support OpenCL1.2, and unofficially support OpenCL2.0 (I'm not using any unsupported functions from 2.0 that I'm aware of, only the unofficially supported ones). I'm guessing I get a compilation error with "-g" because it's not officially or unofficially supported by NVidia yet. Is there a way to get NVidia's latest drivers to spit out better errors? A different flag, perhaps?

As a side note, I can get enqueue_kernel working for some child kernels, and not others...so it's not a matter of enqueue_kernel simply being unsupported on my drivers/hardware, hence the need to understand the error codes I'm getting.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this question? I am running into the same issue I need to be able to see the enqueue kernel error code and -1 isn't very helpful :/

Comment: @PorterMorgan Unfortunately no, I ultimately went with a different approach than using enqueue_kernel altogether.

Answer (score -1):

-11 is `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`. It's in the `cl.h` header, and also see https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/

That code means your program has an error. Use `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with the flag `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG` to get the build log and learn the error.

Comment: No, the error is happening when calling enqueue_kernel inside my kernel, not when building the program. It's a runtime code not a compile code.

Comment: OpenCL error codes don't have different meaning depending on the command, so it's still CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE. It should not be returned from clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. Seems like a driver bug or a bug in your program.

Comment: It's not coming from clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. It's coming from enqueue_kernel, a completely different command, with it's own set of error codes.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for my pre-coffee confusion. I've never used that feature. Perhaps the CLK_* error codes reuse the same number range. They seem to be defined here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/spirv-1.0/lib/Headers/opencl.h (-11 is not listed)